# Qt threads - new way verification please

Tags: qt, qthread

So new to Qt. Read the wiki and C++ Gui programming book and they say subclass QThread. Found that this is not the recommended way now.

So I have some practice code here and I have some questions about if this is correct. So I would really appreciate someone having a look please.

So I created a class with the QThread as a private member to use for the movetothread. When creating it, I made sure not to specify a parent. Therefore my first question is, is this ok to do?

Second question comes from the m_thread->quit(); I found that my connect to finished wasn't being emitted until I did this. So is this the correct way? I read http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/ and saw that the connect between finished and deleteLater in the same thread but not 100% sure if this should be used with quit.

Finally, with the talk of deleteLater, does this mean I dont need 
    delete m_thread

Thanks for anyones time.

Code here. Simple QDialog with a pushbutton.
**worker.cpp**

```
#include "worker.h"

worker::worker(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    stopped = false;
}

void worker::setupAndRun()
{
    m_thread = new QThread();
    connect(m_thread,SIGNAL(started()),this,SLOT(doWork()));
    connect(m_thread,SIGNAL(finished()),this,SLOT(onComplete()));
    connect(m_thread,SIGNAL(finished()),m_thread,SLOT(deleteLater()));
    this->moveToThread(m_thread);
    m_thread->start();
}

void worker::doWork()
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
    {
        if (this->stopped)
            break;
        qDebug() << i << " : " <<  Q_FUNC_INFO << m_thread->currentThreadId();
    }
    // --- I think the quit calls the finished signal?
    m_thread->quit();

}

void worker::onComplete()
{
    qDebug() <<  Q_FUNC_INFO << "Called " << m_thread->currentThreadId();
}
```

**worker.h**

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

class worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit worker(QObject *parent = 0);
    void setupAndRun();
signals:

public slots:
    void doWork();
    void onComplete();
private:
    // --- The thread that I use to movetothread with.
    // Is this ok?
    QThread *m_thread;
    bool stopped;
};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

**Dialog push button**

```
void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    m_worker = new worker();
    m_worker->setupAndRun();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not spot anything much at a glance, but something:

Since `m_thread` is member variable, you should handle it a bit differently. You could initialize it to `null` in the constructor, and also set `m_thread = null` after calling `m_thread->quit()`, since it will get deleted shortly after and you do not want a dangling pointer.

With this code, you should connect the finished signal to m_worker's deleteLater() too, as it appears there is no other code to delete that. You should also take care of threads when application exits, for example with [qAddPostRoutine](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#qAddPostRoutine), so that all threads terminate and all related objects get deleted.

Comment: Hi hyde. Thanks for the reply. But when I add the m_worker as the parent I get a crash after I run with this in the output: QThread::wait: Thread tried to wait on itself
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
ASSERT failure in QMutex::lock: "Internal error, infinite wait has timed out.", file thread/qmutex.cpp, line 452

Comment: Ok, if you did no other changes, it may be that thread object can't be child of a QObject with thread affinity to it. Editing my answer just in case, avoid wrong info...

Comment: Thank you hyde. Appreciate your time.